# On a certain improper integral

Tags: measure-theory

Let $x_1, \cdots,  x_N$  be a finite sequence of real numbers. The
number
$$
D_N = D_N(x_1, \cdots, x_N) = \sup_{0 \le \alpha < \beta \le 1}\big|\frac{\#(\{ x_1, \cdots, x_N \} \cap [\alpha,\beta))}{N}-(\beta-\alpha)\big|
$$
is called the discrepancy of the given sequence. For an infinite sequence $\omega=(x_k)_{k \in N}$
of real numbers (or for a finite sequence containing at least $N$ terms), the
discrepancy $D_N(\omega))$ is meant to be the discrepancy of the initial segment
formed by the first $N$ terms of $\omega$.

Let $f$ be a Lebesgue integrable  positive  increasing continuous real-valued function on $(0,1)$ which is not bounded at point $x=1$.
  Is the following equality 
    $$
  \lambda^{\infty}(\{ \omega=(x_k)_{k \in N} : \lim_{N \to \infty}D_N(\omega) f(x^{*}_N)=0  \})=1
  $$
  valid,  where $x^{*}_N=\max\{ x_k : 1 \le k \le N\}$ and $\lambda^{\infty}$ denotes the infinite power of the linear Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ in $(0,1)$?